# defining serial ports

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For all my current drivers it seems they use 'ttyUSB#' for reading inputs (see example below)

def **init**(self, default_port='/dev/ttyUSB0'):

What are the definitions for reading other port types (especially UART)?

or, a link to a reference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57461/defining-serial-ports/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It obviously depends on the device.

UARTs you'll usually find at `/dev/ttyS*`

Some devices as Hokuyos or newer Arduinos also show up at `/dev/ttyACM*`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-03-08**:
This is good information. Are these and other different port address schemes documented somewhere? It would be good to know the reference.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-08**:
AFAIK not in general as it depends on the driver what devices that one brings up. There might be some official overview, though.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-08**:
In most cases it's also quite simple to figure out: Check `dmesg` output before and after plugging a device. There should be some message with the /dev/... if there is one. This doesn't work with anything that is already connected to the system like a COM port.